# Function does not automatically update when values are changed, except first cells in ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I have created an `Excel` / `VBA` function to calculate students marks having the features:

- Two ranges are formed through only first cells specified up to Number of cells right: 
  one for marks_obtained and other for Maximum_marks
- Total Number of subjects to study
- if all cells in Rng1 are blank then returns "_"
- if a single cell in Rng1 has the word "Left" then returns "Left"
- if total number of cells containing marks in Rng1 are less than NUm argumnt then returns "RL"
- if Else: then calculates in two forms i.e. Subtotal if True & Sum if False

All is working *but*, the problem is:

> It does not update automatically as the values are changed on worksheet.

It requires using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> or Edit (<kbd>F2</kbd>) then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The honorable experts are requested to assist me thanks.

```
Function RSLT_N(r1 As Range, r2 As Range, Num As Integer, Level As Integer, Optional Calc_Type As Boolean = False)

Dim i As Byte
        If Level = 1 Then
          i = 40
        ElseIf Level = 2 Then
          i = 45
        Else
          RSLT_N = "Error"
         ' Exit Function
        GoTo L1
        End If

Dim cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range, cell3 As Range, cell4 As Range
Dim Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range
    Set cell1 = Cells(r1.Row, r1.Column)
    Set cell2 = Cells(r1.Row, r1.Column + Num - 1)
    Set cell3 = Cells(r2.Row, r2.Column)
    Set cell4 = Cells(r2.Row, r2.Column + Num - 1)

    Set Rng2 = Range(cell3, cell4)
    Set Rng1 = Range(cell1, cell2)

    With WorksheetFunction

        If Check_Left(Rng1) Then
            RSLT_N = "Left"
            GoTo L1

        ElseIf .CountBlank(Rng1) = Num Then
            RSLT_N = "-"

        ElseIf .Count(Rng1) < Num Then
            RSLT_N = "RL"
            GoTo L1
        Else

            For c = 1 To Num
                If Rng1.Cells(1, c) / Rng2.Cells(1, c) * 100 < i Then
                    RSLT_N = "RL"
                    GoTo L1
                End If
            Next

            If Calc_Type = True Then
                RSLT_N = .Subtotal(109, Rng1)
                GoTo L1
            ElseIf Calc_Type = False Then
                RSLT_N = .Sum(Rng1)
                GoTo L1
            Else
                RSLT_N = "Error"
                GoTo L1
            End If

        End If
    End With

L1:
End Function

Function Check_Left(Rng As Range)
    Dim strTextString, Str As String
    Dim btCount As Byte
        btCount = Rng.Cells.Count

            For c = 1 To btCount
                On Error GoTo Last
                Set cl = Rng.Cells(1, c)
                strTextString = strTextString & cl
            Next

    With WorksheetFunction
        On Error GoTo Last
        Str = .IsNumber(.Search("left", strTextString))
    End With

        Check_Left = True
        Exit Function
Last:     Check_Left = False
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Level argument means: 1 for Bachelor Level and 2 for Masters level Program/class. And Minimum passing marks for Bachelors are 40 and for Masters 45. Variable "i" and an "if" has been used to check for which level's calculation is required. Regards,

Comment: when you say `when the values are changed on the worksheet`, are those values the parameters of your function?

Comment: a little tip: `Str As String` - `Str` is a very bad name for variable since there is a built-in VBA function `Str(number)`

Comment: yes, to change values means the values of Function parameters

Comment: a format for applying Function: Marks_Obtained
66,56,45,44,55 Out-Of 150,100,50,100,75

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to insert on your code:

```
application.calculatefull
```

Hope it works with you.

Andre

p.s. i forgot to mention, there are some calculation methods:

F9 - Recalculate

```
Application.Calculate
```

CTRL/ALT/F9 – Full Calculation

In Excel 2000/2002/2003:

```
Application.CalculateFull
```

Shift F9 – Sheet Recalculate

```
Worksheets(“SheetName”).Calculate
```

Range Calculate

```
Range(“$a$1:$d$10”).Calculate
```

(I think now it is a more complete answer)

Comment: These methods return Error, none of these work, thanks